# Is it possible to inject css into a TextView that is using Html.FromHtml?

Tags: c#, java, android, xamarin

I have a TextView that is getting it's text from Html.FromHtml.

```
public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
      ISpanned marketingText = Html.FromHtml(ViewModel.Html);
      var text = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.marketingText);
      text.TextFormatted = marketingText;
}
```

Is it possible to inject a CSS file into this? Or should I be using a WebView?

I am using xamarin, c#, but any Java responses are also welcome as it can be translated.

Comment: Hello @Daisy. For what?

Comment: Hi @R.id.pandacoder, for what? Why do I want to style the html? The block of html has tables in it, and needs css to style it. This html content is from pulled in from an outside source, so I can't host it. Hence why we are pulling it in like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TextViews can only contain a small subset of HTML tags not CSS. These tags include `<strong>`, `<underline`>, `<emphasis`>, `<p>`, `<small>`, `<medium>` etc. There are a few others as well.

You can change the font and font colour by doing something like

```
<p font-color="blue">This is my blue text</p>
```

but you can't add CSS. If you need to do formatting in this way that would require CSS then a webview would be better.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't inject CSS into the TextView's HTML, you can however apply certain attributes to the TextView in the XML Editor. For example: `android:textColorLink="#ff0000"` will set all `<a href` HTML tags in the TextView to be red.